# Shoe-themed race or class features

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, character-development

My character is really into shoes and I'm planning on taking Leadership next level. I want my cohort to be devoted to the old norse god of shoes and vengance, [Víðarr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%AD%C3%B0arr). While there is a retribution cleric domain, I'd like to see how far I can go with the shoe theme. **What character traits and abilities in pathfinder are especially evocative of shoes?**

Comment: This question is so awesome I wasn't sure you were serious.

Comment: @Miniman: I'd never joke about my character's devotion to the shoe god. There is nothing at all funny about that.

Comment: Also, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYbjDv62-QQ) is a pronunciation guide for people who aren't familiar with the letter ð.

Comment: You know, with a bit of polish, this concept could really shine. Just don't walk all over the GM, or he could boot you from the table.

Comment: This is Dan's DM. This question is legit, his character is devoted to Víðarr, and it's great. Just to clarify, I fully support this character building decision and if rules need to be fudged to make something interesting work I'm completely for it. So if you have a great idea that fits the spirit of the game but doesn't follow RAW, please post it.

Comment: @GustavBertram the sole thing I want right now is to think of another pun. Then we'll be tied.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is, by far, the *oddest* question I've ever tried to answer.  Here goes.

The [Blade Boot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/blade-boot) is a light martial weapon that extends from the tip of your boot, and is hidden otherwise.  There's a feat for making it more useful as well, [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/drop-dead-studios/combat-feats---3rd-party---drop-dead-studios/-dropdeadstudios-combat-feats-blade-boot-combat).

The [Humble Beginnings](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/humble-beginnings-varisia-smaller-settlements) trait lets you be proficient when using a boot as an improvised weapon.

The [Haunted Boots](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/shoes-haunted) fit with a worshipper of Víðarr, especially if you flavour the ghostly spirits as the souls of the vengeful dead.

There are, of course, a number of foot-slot magic items in addition to this, but I can't find anything else that specifically deals with shoes, boots, sandals, footgear, or several other synonyms for "shoe".

Comment: The haunted boots are especially amazing.

Answer (score 25):

If you're willing to dip into the realm of third-party publishers, one of the more reputable out there, Dreamscarred Press, has released a subsystem inspired by D&D 3.5 edition's *Magic of Incarnum*: **[Akashic Mysteries](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9o6i?Akashic-Mysteries)**.

It has a number of veils (Lavawalker's Boots, Immovable Boots, Coward's Boots, and Lover's Tread) that can be shaped for minor benefits, and later bound to the Feet chakra for special effects.

Answer (score 16):

In Pathfinder, you get two domains.  If the second aspect of Víðarr you want your Cleric to focus on is Shoes, you should take the Shoes domain.  The game designers seemed not to have included such a domain in the Core Rulebook or any of the auxiliary materials yet published, but by working with your GM you should be able to cobble up a solution to this problem.  Ask her to write up a homebrew domain for you, or use the one I have provided below.

## Shoes

**Associated Domain:** Artifice

**Replacement Power:** The following power replaces the *Dancing Weapons* power of the Artifice domain.

*Iron Booted Foothold(Su)*: As a Move Action you can strike down any opponent not immune to tripping, trapping them beneath a divinely imbued sole.  This functions as a trip attack except that you may only target adjacent opponents who are adjacent to a hard surface, it does not provoke attacks of opportunity even if you do not have Improved Trip, and your opponent may not attempt to trip you if your attempt fails.  You receive a bonus on this trip attempt equal to twice your level in the class that grants you access to this domain.  If successful, your opponent gains both the prone and pinned conditions.  The pinned condition lasts for a number of rounds equal to your Wisdom modifier (minimum 1) or until the pinned creatures successfully breaks free, whichever comes first.  The pinned condition also ends if you move more than 5 feet from your target.  You do not gain the grappled condition and you do not have to spend actions to maintain the grapple.  As long as this effect lasts you gain a bonus to your CMD equal to your level in the class granting access to this domain. Whenever the pinned condition applied due to this ability ends on an opponent, you may choose either to maintain the pin as a regular grapple-- in which case you must successfully make a valid check under the normal rules to maintain the grapple (and gain the grappled condition), but your opponent does not lose the pinned condition-- or end the grapple as not-an-action.

You can use this ability once a day at 8th level, plus once a day for every four levels you attain beyond 8th.

Replacement Spells: 2nd--Air Step, 3rd--Anchored Step, 8--Irresistible Dance, 9--Miracle

Comment: I would have thought to house-rule a modification to the travel domain. Artifice is really clever.